# error calling ReportingService2005.FindItems(); specifically concerning the BooleanOperatorEnum parameter

Tags: .net, powershell, reporting-services

Having issues calling the ReportingService2005.FindItems() method from within powershell v2.

```
$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -Namespace SSRS.ReportingService2005 -UseDefaultCredential;

$searchCondition = New-Object SSRS.ReportingService2005.SearchCondition
$searchCondition.ConditionSpecified  = $true
$searchCondition.Name = "Name";
$searchCondition.Value = "Sales";
[SSRS.ReportingService2005.SearchCondition[]] $searchConditions = @($searchCondition)

$boolOp = [SSRS.ReportingService2005.BooleanOperatorEnum]::And

#Also tried bellow initialization of enum.
#[SSRS.ReportingService2005.BooleanOperatorEnum] $boolOp = 0

$rs.FindItems("/", $boolOp ,$searchConditions)
```

Executing the above gives the following error:

Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "And", for "FindItems" to type "SSRS.ReportingService2005.BooleanOperatorEnum": "Cannot convert value "And" to type "SSRS.ReportingService2005.BooleanOperatorEnum". Error: "Invalid cast from 'SSRS.ReportingService2005.BooleanOperatorEnum' to 'SSRS.ReportingService2005.BooleanOperatorEnum'.""

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determined error to be related to the namespace paramater used in my webproxy. As it turns out, my script as posted runs successfully the first time it is excecuted in a session; it fails on successive executions in the same powershell session.

Found this article which explains the situation fairly well: http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/273120-bug-when-using-namespace-parameter-new-webserviceproxy.html

```
$rs = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $ReportServerUri -UseDefaultCredential; 

$searchCondition = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1er_ReportService2005_asmx_WSDL.SearchCondition;
$boolop = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1er_ReportService2005_asmx_WSDL.BooleanOperatorEnum;
```